# Is there a way in Hamcrest to test for a value to be a number?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Is there a way to test that an expected value is a number using Hamcrest without extending the library ?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
    assertThat(expectedValue).isNumber();
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that expectedValue is a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own Matcher:

```
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class IsLong extends TypeSafeMatcher<String> {

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(String s) {
        try {
            Long.parseLong(s); // Or the number type you need
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("is long");
    }

    public static Matcher<String> isLong() {
        return new IsLong();
    }
}
```

So your code will looks like

```
assertThat(expectedValue, isLong());
```

More info at http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/tutorial  (Writing custom matchers section)