# How to validate response in one attempt

Tags: rest-assured

I want to test the response for POST request to petstore.swagger.io. I receive a response, why cannot I validate the body with path "id"? I always got errors, but regex is right and tested.

Test method:

```
@Test
    public void postPet() {
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("<(\\d*)>");
        Response response = given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body(jsonObject)
        .when()
                .post(String.format("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet"))
        .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .log().body()
                .and()
                .assertThat()
                .body("id", matchesPattern(pt))
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path id doesn't match.
Expected: a string matching the pattern '<(\d*)>'
  Actual: <9223372000666122518L>
```

The response body is:

```
{
    "id": 9223372000666122443,
    "category": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string"
    },
    "name": "doggie",
    "photoUrls": [
        "string"
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "string"
        }
    ],
    "status": "available"
}
```

And what is the L at the end of the id string? In swagger, there is no L as well as in the Postman. I tried regex without "< , >".

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of clear that

- your `id` is `9223372000666122518L`, `L` means `long` (data type)
- you use regex, but it only works for `String`

--> type mistmach when comparing `long` vs `String`

Solution:

1. Convert `id` to `String` first then assert

```
long id = ...log().body()
                .extract().path("id");

assertThat(String.valueOf(id), Matchers.matchesPattern("\\d+"));
```

or

2. Write a custom Matcher, to check `isLong`, like this [Is there a way in Hamcrest to test for a value to be a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58099695/is-there-a-way-in-hamcrest-to-test-for-a-value-to-be-a-number)

Comment: But for 0 it also does not work. I mean when I check category.id.

Comment: I've tested solution 1 for both cases, it works fine. Did you try this?